# Прокрутка вверх и вниз. Как отследить направление

Tags: javascript, jquery

Желательно с использованием jquery. Находил статейки на тостере, но рабочего варианта не получил, решил спросить тут более конкретно.
$(window).scrollTop() - позволяет отследить насколько прокрутили вниз, но не понимаю как использовать эту функцию, чтобы узнать крутим ли вверх или вниз.

По человечески понимаю, что это должно работать как-то так:

- Если scrollTop() > текущего положения, то ВНИЗ.
- Если scrollTop() <    текущего положения, то ВВЕРХ.

Непонятно только как регистрировать текущее положение.

Comment: на английском SO  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
if (st > lastScrollTop){
   // downscroll code
} else {
   // upscroll code
}
lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

или

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
    console.log('Scroll up');
}
else {
    console.log('Scroll down');
}
});
```